# Why error with my code

Tags: haskell

In this script,

```
data Move = Rock | Paper | Scissor
            deriving (Show,Eq)
    lose Rock       = Scissor
lose Paper      = Rock
lose _          = Paper

data Result = Win | Draw | Lose
              deriving (Show,Eq)

outcome :: Move -> Move -> Result
outcome x y
  | con1      == Win
  where
  con1 = (y==(lose x))
```

I wonder why there is a

> `parse error on input "where"`

Thanks for your advance!

Comment: The problem is probably that `con1` is on the wrong indentation level for the `where` block. You need to ensure that the code you've pasted in looks like the code in your editor so we can see what's misaligned.

Comment: @MrBones indentation isn't the problem. I pasted the code exactly as-is, without an indentation error. it's related to the use of `==` instead of `=` in the line above.

Comment: Fixing the indentation won't do harm, though.

Answer (score 4):

In the line before the `where` you are using `==` when you probably meant `=`.